# How to make an ifelse statement for each row in a table

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, rstudio

I'm trying to make an ifelse statement giving a result for each row in a table  with undefined rows based on certain columns.

It is in R studio

I have a matrix looking like this

```
Resp  Acdev weight  EQR    S1   S2  S3  refcon  status 
1        2     3     4       5   6   7      NA       9
0       11    12    13      14  15  16       1      18
1       20    21    22      23  24  25       2      21
0       29    30    31      32  33  34       1      NA
```

The data is called Phyto.

I wish to find get the result "0" if all numbers in a row a different from "NA" and "1" if 1 value in a row is "NA".

When I try to use the code

```
l=ifelse((Phyto[,8]!="" && Phyto[,2]!="" && Phyto[,9]!="" && Phyto[,3]!="" && Phyto[,1]!=""),0,1)
I get the result "1", but would like to get the result "1", "0", "1", "0"
```

Since the code should be used on data set with varying number of rows it would be preferable if I could make a code that does not include a fixed number of rows.

Does anyone has a suggestion for the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What language & system is this? Please give example input, output, and expected output. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the post, hope it helps!

Comment: Consider adding an [rstudio] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to get the result `1, 0, 0, 1`

This should do it

```
l <- ifelse(is.na(rowSums(Phyto)),1,0)
```

Some test data

```
Phyto <- rbind(c(2, 3, 5), c(4, NA, 11), c(5, 5, 5), c(7, 1, NA))
l <- ifelse(is.na(rowSums(Phyto)),1,0)
```

Yields

```
> Phyto
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    5
[2,]    4   NA   11
[3,]    5    5    5
[4,]    7    1   NA
> l
[1] 0 1 0 1
```